# Plot two line graphs within one chart with shared time x-axis in R axis.Date not working

Tags: r, charts, line, axis

running following code in R:

```
#################### PLOT DIAMOND HANDS AND RETURNS ##################### 

## add extra space to right margin of plot within frame
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 6) + 0.1)

## Plot first set of data and draw its axis
plot(df$time, df$returns, pch=16, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0,-0.4), xlab="", ylab="", 
   type="l",col="black", main="GME Returns and Diamond Hands popularity")
axis(2, ylim=c(0,1),col="black",las=1)  ## las=1 makes horizontal labels

mtext("GME Returns",side=2,line=2.5)
box()

## Allow a second plot on the same graph
par(new=TRUE)

## Plot the second plot and put axis scale on right
plot(df$time, df$Diamond.Hands, pch=15,  xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(0,1), 
    axes=FALSE, type="l", col="red")
## a little farther out (line=4) to make room for labels
mtext("Diamond Hands",side=4,col="red",line=4) 
axis(4, ylim=c(0,1), col="red",col.axis="red",las=1)

## Draw the time axis
axis(1,pretty(range(df$time),10))


# axis(1,pretty(range(df$time),10))
mtext("Time",side=1,col="black",line=2.5)  

## Add Legend
# legend("topleft",legend=c("GME Returns","Diamond Hands Popularity"),
# text.col=c("black","red"),pch=c(16,15),col=c("black","red"))
```

The result looks like this: As Time is not correctly formated. The time data itself was defined previously as:

```
df$time <- strptime(df$time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = 'GMT')
```

Can anyone please help me formatting it correctly?

With axis.Date the axis is just disappearing[image]

Maybe you have also an idea how i could get rid of the gaps in the time series?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Data

| time | returns | Diamond.Hands |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-16 10:00:00 | -0.0037586920 | 0.4583333 |
| 2021-02-16 11:00:00 | -0.0157776108 | 0.5000000 |
| 2021-02-16 21:00:00 | -0.50761421 | 0.43948956 |
| 2021-02-17 08:00:00 | -0.00142141 | 0.89114565 |
| 2021-02-17 09:00:00 | -0.48694561 | 0.15894415 |
| 2021-02-17 10:00:00 | -0.45861415 | 0.35784893 |
| 2021-02-17 11:00:00 | -0.56869411 | 0.32154861 |
| 2021-02-17 12:00:00 | -0.21356147 | 0.48692132 |
| 2021-02-17 18:00:00 | -0.21345648 | 0.12345671 |
| 2021-02-17 19:00:00 | -0.56521356 | 0.23148489 |
| 2021-02-17 20:00:00 | -0.75656187 | 0.35258644 |

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: i added some in the initial post

Answer (score 0):

Solved it via ggplot2:

```
#Filter only for negative return hours
df1 <- df %>% filter(returns < 0)

# Calculate moving average of returns for 10 days
df1$MAreturns <- TTR::SMA(df1$returns,n=10)

# Calculate moving average of Diamond Hands for 10 days
df1$Diamond.Hands=na.approx(df1$Diamond.Hands)
df1$MADiamond.Hands <- TTR::SMA(df1$Diamond.Hands,n=10)
df1$MADiamond.Hands <- df1$MADiamond.Hands*-1
head(df1)

# Plot graph
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = as.POSIXct(time), y = returns)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/5)+
  # coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,-0.2)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Diamond.Hands*-1), alpha = 1/5)+
  geom_line(aes(y=MAreturns, color="10 day moving average of GME returns"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=MADiamond.Hands, color="10 day moving average of Diamond Hands"))+
  xlab("Time")+
  ylab("Negative GME returns")+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", limits=c(0,-0.5), sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~.*-1, name="Popularity of diamond hands flair"))+
  labs(color='Legend')+
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", 
        values = c("10 day moving average of Diamond Hands" = "blue", 
                "10 day moving average of GME returns" = "red"))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.125, 0.925))+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 14))+
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,3,1,1), "cm"))+
  theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(vjust=3))+
  theme(axis.title.y.left = element_text(vjust=3))+
  scale_x_datetime(
    breaks = seq(as.POSIXct("2021-02-16 00:59:00 CET"),
                 as.POSIXct("2021-10-01 00:59:00 CET"), "1 month"),
    labels = date_format("%b", tz = "CET"),
    expand = c(0, 0),
    limits = c(
      as.POSIXct("2021-02-16 00:00:00 CET"),
      as.POSIXct("2021-10-01 00:00:00 CET")
    )
  )
```